# How to catch and report exception caught by rendering library in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I would like to catch and report when UI exception occurs in app. I would like to report it with firebase tools or save in local activity log, but I don't know where to catch it?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to handle the UI exception?

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics has a way of doing it.  It has a way of listening to Flutter Errors and will record it on Firebase:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
```

You can also replace the FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError with whatever your service you want to use.

```
FlutterError.onError = //whatever service you use.
```